# A complete MIPS Processor(Datapath+Control Unit) for the following subset of MIPS instructions:

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

ALU instructions (R-type): add, sub, and, or, xor, slt
Immediate instructions (I-type): addi, slti, andi, ori, xori
Load and Store (I-type): lw, sw
Branch (I-type): beq, bne
Jump (J-type): j
the internal circuit of all components used in the datapath(ALU, adder, Extender, and ...) should be included in your design. You can use 32-bit adder, decoder , multiplexer, Memory, and Registers as the predefined component in your design,

I cant find any images how to combine all the three types and make a single cycle process

Answer (score 1):

[Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=MIPS+single+cycle+datapath+diagram&iax=images&ia=images) for MIPS single cycle datapath diagram to find many images that have the hardware for R-Types, and I-types including branch and load.

Usually, what's missing from these diagrams is the J-Type instructions, including both `j` and `jal` — both need to combine the upper 4 bits of the PC with a 26-bit immediate (some have this), and the `jal` also needs to capture the (next) PC into the `$ra` register, which is in the register file (few, if any, have this).  (`jalr` usually also missing, it needs to capture the return address also into one register, and, set the PC = the other register's value).

The approach to combining what might appear as unrelated circuits is: ***splicing***.  If we were doing software, splicing two designs together would look like this:

Design 1:

```
// sequential execution, increment the PC by 1 instruction word
// this is used by R-Types and also I-Types that are arithmetic 
// (and also by I-Types that are conditional branches that are not taken)
PC = PC + 4
```

Design 2:

```
// branch taken, change flow of control
// this is used by I-Type conditional branches for taken branches, e.g. beq, bne
PC = PC + sxt(imm)`
```

Splice these together: this requires a control signal to choose which design to take, and given the control signal, the combined design will be able to do either Design 1 or Design 2.  Let's call the control signal `Branch`.

Combined Designs 1 & 2:

```
// Choose Design 1 or Design 2 by control of "Branch"
PC = Branch ? PC + sxt(imm) : PC + 4
```

We can see in the MIPS single cycle datapath diagrams, that this splicing is being done — control signal `Branch` informs this PC assignment circuitry whether to choose sequential execution or conditional taken branch address.  (The conditional branch circuitry also checks to see if the branch should be taken or not, as output by control signal `Zero` from the ALU, so is a bit more complex, as in `PC = (Branch & Zero) ? PC + sxt(imm) : PC + 4`)

The main operator for this kind of splicing in C is the `?:` pair, the conditional choice, and key here, of course, is the requirement for an indicator to choose between the two options (as in `choice ? option1 : option2`)

To splice together choice of three or more options, two or more `?:` operators can be combined, given appropriate control signals.

In hardware the equivalent of C's ?: operator is the MUX.  A MUX takes three inputs, two are data path inputs and one is a (one-bit, i.e. boolean) control signal.  The MUX then chooses, based on the value of the control signal one of the two inputs to pass to its output.  This is the same functionality as the ?: operator: two datapath-sized (e.g. 32 bit) inputs, one boolean input and one output

Looking at one of these MIPS single cycle datapath diagrams, let's observe that every MUX shown is doing this kind of splicing of two different design choices for what value to pass on.  Each MUX is given a control signal that tells it which input to pass through and thus also which one to ignore.

Comment: I tried to draw it on my own on A1 paper like every different component seperate which means I type J type and R type but I dont know how to link each of them but your answer is helping me to understand it